# Replace functions in nodejs module with mock functions

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, unit-testing, nodeunit

I'm creating a small project in nodejs that is a wrapper for an API. I'm writing some unit tests using [nodeunit](https://github.com/caolan/nodeunit) and need to inject various mock functions into the module (for example a function that simulates making a HTTP request to the server and outputs various different responses to test my code against).

The question I have is how do I inject these functions into my module?

I've identified two methods that should theoretically work as follows:

## Method 1

Rename the folders of the modules I would like to replace and add a new folder containing the code I'd like to inject e.g:

```
./node_modules/request -> ./node_modules/request.tmp
./tests/myRandomFunction -> ./node_modules/request
```

After performing the tests I would then do the opposite:

```
./node_modules/request -> ./tests/myRandomFunction
./node_modules/request.tmp -> ./node_modules/request
```

This seems rather hacky and is not something I'd like to attempt even though it should theoretically work.

## Method 2

This is my preferred method utilising my modules initialisation. My module takes a JSON object that can contain various options as follows:

```
var module = require('./module')({
  option1: '',
  option2: '',
  ...
});
```

I am planning on adding a key to this JSON object called '_testing' with the value of a JSON object containing various functions for example:

```
var module = require('./module')({
  _testing: {
    request: function() {return false;}
  }
});
```

In my module I could then do the following:

- If this._testing exists and is a JSON object
- Loop over this._testing
- For each key in this._testing
- Replace the function with the same name as the key with its value e.g

```
eval(''+key+' = this._testing.'+key) //eval('request = this._testing.request')
/*
eval can be dangerous I should probably perform some validation for example is key a function we want to be replaced? Can I check if nodeunit is testing my module and if it isn't don't do anything?
*/
```

Is there a better way to inject / replace a function in my module for testing purposes?

Answer (score 2):

I have used [Mockery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mockery) for this purpose

And for testing HTTP calls [Nock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nock)

They both offer a lot cleaner approach

Answer (score 1):

This is called "mocking" or "stubbing". It's a common necessity while testing, and there's a variety of libraries. Possibly the most popular is [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/).

With Sinon you can do something like `var stub = sinon.stub(request, [methodName]).returns(false)` (or any other return value). You can also do things like `stub.expects(42)` to assert that the function receives that as a parameter when invoked.